# I am trying to parse a simple expression but it has an infinite loop

Tags: parsing, haskell, text-parsing, parsec

I want to parse a language like this

```
foo = (bar, bar1 = (bar2 = bar4), bar5)
```

I wrote a simple parser

```
module SimpleParser where
import Text.Parsec.String (Parser)
import Text.Parsec.Language (emptyDef)
import Text.Parsec
import qualified Text.Parsec.Token as Tok
import Text.Parsec.Char
import Prelude

lexer :: Tok.TokenParser ()
lexer = Tok.makeTokenParser style
  where
    style = emptyDef {
              Tok.identLetter    = alphaNum
             }

parens :: Parser a -> Parser a
parens = Tok.parens lexer

commaSep :: Parser a -> Parser [a]
commaSep = Tok.commaSep lexer

identifier :: Parser String
identifier = Tok.identifier lexer

reservedOp :: String -> Parser ()
reservedOp = Tok.reservedOp lexer

data Expr = Ident String | Label String Expr | ExprList [Expr] deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

parseExpr :: String -> Either ParseError Expr
parseExpr s = parse expr "" s

expr :: Parser Expr
expr = parens expr
      <|> try exprList
      <|> ident
ident :: Parser Expr
ident = do
  var <- identifier
  return $ Ident var

exprLabel :: Parser Expr
exprLabel = do
  var <- identifier
  reservedOp "="
  body <- expr
  return $ Label var body

exprList :: Parser Expr
exprList = do
  list <- commaSep (try exprLabel <|> expr)
  return $ ExprList list
```

But even with the following simple input it has an infinite loop:

```
test = parseExpr "foo = bar"
```

Could someone explain why it doesn't work and how I can fix it?

Comment: This kind of nasty behaviour is usually related to left recursion on grammars. I do not have enough time to check, but I believe that using `chainl` or `chainr` could help. Later, I'll check on your code and try to fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thing is, in your code, `exprList` will loop if it tries to
parse an identifier, that is `parse exprList "" "foo"` goes into
an infinite loop. This is because it tries to parse it as a list
of either Labels or expressions, and expressions can be lists. Once
it fails to be a `exprLabel` it tries to see if it can be a `expr` and so
it calls `exprList` again.

To fix it you need to make sure that `expr` checks to see both if it is
a `exprLabel` or an `identifier` before it tries `exprList`. Note that if
all the above fails it will still go into a loop. This is because it doesn't know if this is just the start of a list (or a list of lists of lists of lists...) or not.

To fix this you can make `expr` only call `exprList` if it matches a `parens`, and use `exprList` as the starting `Parser`.

```
expr :: Parser Expr
expr = parens (exprList)
      <|> try exprLabel
      <|> ident

exprList :: Parser Expr
exprList = do
  list <- commaSep expr
  return $ ExprList list
```

And it works like this:

```
>parse exprList  "" "(foo=bar),foo=bar"
  Right (ExprList [ExprList [Label "foo" (Ident "bar")],Label "foo" (Ident "bar")])
```

Comment: `Note that if all the above fails it will still infinitely.` Is there any way to prevent it?

Comment: @ais , sorry I forgot to remove `exprList` as an option for `expr`. It shouldn't go in a loop now.